# Is it a bug for getFeaturesAtPixel(pixel, opt_options)?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

When I used this function to get features, I found that:
If the 'Style' (like image and text) of a 'Feature' is within 100 pixels of the feature's coordinate, I can get the feature by using the pixels within the 'Style';
But If the 'Style' is too far (more than 100 pixels), I cannot get the 'Feature' by using the pixels of the 'Style'.

e.g. adding the 'ol/style/Text' into a Style of a feature.

```
new Text({
  font: '15px Microsoft YaHei',
  text: '',
  fill: new Fill({
    color: '#222'
  }),
  backgroundStroke: new Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    width: 1
  }),
  backgroundFill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(0,250,154,0.3)'
  }),
  textAlign: 'middle',
  textBaseline: 'middle',
  offsetX: 200,
  offsetY: 200
})
```

Comment: Did you try `hitTolerance` option?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, but it's focus on another issue. Big `hitTolerance` can make big range to hit features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution in github: 
By default, OpenLayers only considers an area of 100 pixels around a feature for hit detection. When you use an offset of 200 pixels. you are outside of that region. To fix it, configure your layer with a `renderBuffer` with an appropriate size.